# Something Wrong With Label Using Macro Excel

Tags: excel

First of all, I am so sorry to post this question here. This question is more to mathematics, not programming but I don't know other place to seek help. Basically, my code works to label selection highlighted by the user by using alphabet and number, 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D and etc. There are 20 different styles (1 by 1 label to 20 by 20 label) to label the selected cells. The problem occurs when I choose bigger number like 5 for my first selection, and the first selection finish at 3A (the labeling will be like this: Start: 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 3A, the next selection choose 2 as second selection, the labeling will be incorrect like this: 3B 3C 3D 3E until 3Z and will continue till last cells as number 8 only where the correct labeling should be like this: 4A 4B 5A 5B 6A 6B. I don't even know what is wrong with the code and thus I need help from you. Thank you in advance. These are the code and I just select style 1 to 2 only, the only different thing in the code is the number:

```
Public A, B As Integer

Sub AutoLabel()

'to label the cell in term of 1A and etc
A = 1
B = 1
End Sub

Sub LabelTest()
Dim Cell As Range

With Selection

' allign text so that it is centered between the top and bottom of the cell
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

' allign text so that it is centered between the left and right of the cell
.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

SR = .Row
SC = .Column
LR = SR + .Rows.Count - 1
LC = SC + .Columns.Count - 1
End With

' to input the first cell as 1A, and next cell as 1B and etc
For Each Cell In Selection
Cell.value = B & Mid("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", A, 1)
A = A + 1
If A = 2 Then A = 1: B = B + 1

Next Cell ' run next selected cell by user

End Sub
Sub LabelTest2()
Dim Cell As Range

With Selection

' allign text so that it is centered between the top and bottom of the cell
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

' allign text so that it is centered between the left and right of the cell
.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

SR = .Row
SC = .Column
LR = SR + .Rows.Count - 1
LC = SC + .Columns.Count - 1
End With

' to input the first cell as 1A, and next cell as 1B and etc
For Each Cell In Selection
Cell.value = B & Mid("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", A, 1)
A = A + 1
If A = 3 Then A = 1: B = B + 1

Next Cell ' run next selected cell by user
End Sub
```

[I asked the same question here but no reply](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1180746-something-wrong-with-label-using-macro-excel.html#post4624462)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't think your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow at all.

If I've understood your problem correctly, the following should work:

```
Const ALPHABET As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

Function getLabelNumber(ByVal labelNumber As Integer, ByVal labelsPerPage As Integer) As String
  getLabelNumber = ((labelNumber - 1) \ labelsPerPage) + 1 & Mid(ALPHABET, ((labelNumber - 1) Mod labelsPerPage) + 1, 1)
End Function
```

Then, say you want your cells labelled 1A to 1H, 2A to 2H and so forth up to 10H, you just need to keep track of a single counter (let's call it `i`) and get each label string with `getLabelNumber(i, 8)`.

Your code might be able to make use of this as follows:

```
Dim cellCount As Integer, numCols As Integer
numCols = Selection.Columns.Count
For Each cell In Selection
  cellCount = cellCount + 1
  cell.Value = getLabelNumber(cellCount, numCols)
Next cell
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast assistance. But can you tell me where should I put the function in the coding?

Comment: Or better, provide me with full coding because I am a bit confuse on how to use function. Thank you.

Comment: Declare the constant and the function outside your `Sub`. I've updated the answer with a fragment that better illustrates how you could call it.